# Does JUnit set randomly properties to null?

Tags: java, junit

I have a series of tests methods which exactly depend on each other. I keep having problems with object being set to default state or just their properties being changed to null. In normal program, nothing like this ever happens. Setting things randomly to final seems to help, but I can't modify production code just because of tests.

The fact that setting properties to final also means that it's not in my code - if my code was changing these, compiler wouldn't compile it (no reflection in my code).

Before I dig even deeper in it, could you please tell me whether JUnit should be doing something like this? If yes, what rules can I read about it?

Comment: junit does not set properties to null randomly, junit execute test methods in random order

Comment: "I have a series of tests methods which exactly depend on each other." this is negation of unit test.

Comment: @Kuba [Sure sure.](http://fossies.org/linux/privat/junit4.11.zip/junit4.11/javadoc/org/junit/FixMethodOrder.html)

Answer (score 6):

JUnit does not set anything to `null` randomly. It sets things to `null` very deterministically: before each test method is run, a new instance of the test class is created. Thus, all instance variables are set to the default value, which is `null` for object references.

Unit tests should not depend on each other. They must be runnable in any order. If you have parts that depend on each other, you have to put them in the same test method (or in seperate non-test methods which are called from your test method in the right order).

If you want to initialize data that are required by all tests, you can annotate methods with the `@Before` annotation (this method will then be run before each test method) or with the `@BeforeClass` annotation (this method will then be run once before all test methods).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to initialize some objects before each tests, try to use the annotation @Before to an initialization function.

See http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html

Answer (score 1):

JUnit executes tests in an unpredictable order, so no test should be relying on the execution of any other test. It is also the correct practice to separate your tests like this.

In order to initialize everything, use a method annotated with @Before to set things up, and one with @After to tear things down. Those methods will be executed before and after every test, so you can be sure tests are set up the same and cannot affect each other.

Comment: Slight correction: JUnit executes tests in a _unpredicitable order_. It isn't actually random. By default, the tests will run in the same order each run.